# Create a Dynamic Front end JSP page for a Servlet , And also displaying the output of the Servlet to the JSP page

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, servlets

Say i have a JSP page index.jsp

```
<form action="https://localhost:8080/App/backend_servlet" method="get">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name"><b>User id:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" size="40" title="Please enter Clients User id" ></input>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" title="Please enter Password."></input>
        </li>
        <!-- For the next input tag in the value part it should display the "String output" from the backend_Servlet-->
        <li>
            <label for="name"><b>Output</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="output" id="output" value = "TODAY" title="it should display output as reponse"></input>
        </li>                
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="action">Submit</button>

    </p>
</form>
```

So the above .jsp page contains a form which Requests the **User Name** and **password** from the user . So after the user enters his username and password and clicking submit the page then gets to the **backend_servlet** which processes the request and has to redirect to the same page and has to display **String output** in the output field of the page.

```
public class backend_servlet extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel
{  
// protected static ILogDevice m_oLogDevice;    

protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String ls_userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String ls_pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String output = "";

    //Some Code which processes the userName and pwd and gives some value for the output string.                

    output = "Something";

}
}
```

Is there any  way that i can re-write the code of index.jsp so that it can show me the response String of the servlet.

Without using the `PrintWriter`, `response.getWriter()` in the servlet and redirecting back to some other jsp page.

Comment: Some advice: have a look at Java Naming conventions http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some modification in your JSP code as shown below. Use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) or JSP Expression Language to access the request attribute.

#### Steps to follow:

- At first time load of `index.jsp` the `responseString` will be `null` and nothing will be shown on JSP
- Now after submitting the form to the Servlet, set the `responseString` as request attribute based on user authentication and redirect request to the `index.jsp` page back.
- After redirection the `responseString` will not be `null` in `index.jsp` and will be displayed on the page.

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<form action="https://localhost:8080/App/backend_servlet" method="get">
    ...
</form>

<c:if test="${not empty responseString}">
    <c:out value="${responseString}"></c:out>
</c:if>
```

Servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("responseString", output);
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

---

You can access it based on scope as well:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.responseString}"></c:out>
```

---

#### EDIT

As per your code set it directly in the `title` attribute as shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="output" id="output" 
                   value = "TODAY" title="${responseString}"></input>
```

Comment: Thank you, How can i use the output in this part of the code 
`<input type="text" name="output" id="output" value = "TODAY" title="it should display output as reponse"></input>`

Comment: updated it in my post. It's very simple. if `responseString` is `null` then it set the title to blank and in case of redirection it will set the actual title.

Comment: _ HTTP Status 500 - /index.jsp(23,8) "${responseString ! = null}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${responseString ! = null}] _


Pls let me know why it si showing this error, let me know ifyou want the code snippet

Comment: Simply try the last option. There is no need to put a `null` check. that is handled automatically by EL. If it's `null` then it prints nothing (blank string).

Comment: I need to perform a series of functions on the Servlet , like Connect, send message, logout.
So, that needs to remember the session. But when i try to access the session.getattribute it's returning null pointer exception.
Can you please suggest some method to store the session details.

Comment: It would be good if you can post an another question along with more detail information. It's not clear to me what here you want to achieve.